# AngularJs Ionic Project, $stateProvider not working at all, I already looked for all kind of solutions

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I just started a blank new Ionic project, and I'm going crazy trying to figure out what is wrong with my $stateProvider setup.

My routes.js:

```
    angular.module('starter.routes', [])
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

  $stateProvider
  .state('login', {
      url: '/Login',
      templateUrl: 'templates/Login.html',
      controller: 'loginCtrl'

    });

  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/Login');

});
```

My app.js:

```
angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'starter.routes', 'ui.router'])

.run(function($ionicPlatform, $state, $timeout) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    console.log("platform ready");
    $state.go('login');



    // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
    // for form inputs)
    if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);

    }
    if (window.StatusBar) {
      // org.apache.cordova.statusbar required
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }

  });


});
```

My index.html:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <title></title>

    <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">

    <!-- un-comment this code to enable service worker
    <script>
      if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
        navigator.serviceWorker.register('service-worker.js')
          .then(() => console.log('service worker installed'))
          .catch(err => console.log('Error', err));
      }
    </script>-->

    <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- IF using Sass (run gulp sass first), then uncomment below and remove the CSS includes above
    <link href="css/ionic.app.css" rel="stylesheet">
    -->

    <!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
    <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>

    <!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>

    <!-- your app's js -->
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="js/routes.js"></script>
    <script src="js/controllers/login-ctrl.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="starter">

    <ion-pane>
      <ion-header-bar class="bar-stable">
        <h1 class="title">Ionic Blank Starter</h1>
      </ion-header-bar>
      <ion-content>
      </ion-content>
    </ion-pane>
  </body>
</html>
```

I've already worked on complex ionic apps, and started many on my own, and never had a problem like this, in my app.js, the $state.go('login'); won't work. EVER.
I tried to put that command inside a timeout, or a function but nothing happened, I'm guessing there is something wrong with my declaration of the $stateProvider but I really can't figure out what that could be.. I also tried to copy and pasterino whole sections of working code from other projects...

I really need help!! Thank you!

Comment: where is the ui-view section in your index.html?and you dont need to call your state in platform ready

Comment: That's not needed at all, I never used ui-view in my index, that's only for multiple views on the same template, and it's not what I'm looking for